# Java not starting from init or cron

Tags: linux, java, cron, systemd

We're starting a Java process with following command:

`/usr/bin/java -classpath /home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes:/home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes/mail.jar:/home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes/httpcore-4.4.4.jar core.Main configFile=/home/somejavadaemon/Java/config.cfg`

When started from user's shell (`somejavadaemon`) everything is fine - the daemon is working, and doing what it's supposed to.

Now, we want to do it from Systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=somejavadaemon service
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

[Service]

User=somejavadaemon
Group=somejavadaemon

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Environment=J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Environment=DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
Environment=J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin

ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath /home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes:/home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes/mail.jar:/home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/home/somejavadaemon/Java/classes/httpcore-4.4.4.jar core.Main configFile=/home/somejavadaemon/Java/config.cfg

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

By accounts of Systemd, service starts - the process is in memory. However, when I look into its status, I see following:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
         at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
         at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
         at whois.WhoisThreadPool$WhoisThread.start(WhoisThreadPool.java:319)
         at whois.WhoisThreadPool.init(WhoisThreadPool.java:42)
         at whois.WhoisThreadPool.<init>(WhoisThreadPool.java:36)
         at whois.Whois.<init>(Whois.java:49)
         at core.Main.main(Main.java:110)`

Why is this happening?
How is starting off of Systemd different from starting from user's shell? It's the same thing with cron, we tried to put it there, to similar success.

Comment: What is the memory used by the JVM in both cases? Have you tried to use the `-Xm*` parameters that control the JVM memory size? Did you try to run the command in a terminal using the same id as when started as a daemon?

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11675133 should help answerers.